# Updating url prefix with mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have imported my database by script from live site to my local server.

I have menu system dynamically generated by database. they are in table like below:

```
id   name     linkpage
1    blog     http://www.example.com/blog/index.php
2    about    http://www.example.com/blog/about.php
```

I have to change live url in to my local url like http://www.example.com/blog/index.php to http://localhost/mysite/blog/index.php

How can I update link page column with mysql query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple. You can do with [**replace**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) function:

```
 UPDATE tablename SET linkpage=REPLACE(linkpage,'www.example.com','localhost/nysite')
```

Answer (score 0):

with replace function;

```
mysql_query("UPDATE your_tablename SET linkpage=REPLACE(linkpage,'www.your_link.com','localhost/mysite')")
```